# 2 [][] int Arrays have the exact same values, in the exact same position...How to check that efficiently?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, equals, deepequals

I need help with my Multidimensional int [][] in Java. 
The first one is:

```
int [][] startArr = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
```

The second is:

```
int [][] testArr = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};

Arrays.deepEquals(startArr, testArr)
```

returns false...But why?
If I have such a situation, I want to quit the program. At the moment I am inside of an infinite loop because this check doesn't work properly. 
If one value inside testArr has an other position (then there are two values in different positions of course) than in startArr, it should return false.

Comment: That code returns true for me.  Can you please post your actual testing code?

Comment: That should work. You need to set a breakpoint at the `deepEquals()` line and examine the values in `startArr` and `testArr`.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: I saw that I had a modification on the first array meanwhile, damn I am sorry for wasting your time...
I thought I had removed all operations...

Comment: Your code is OK and return "true". Copy/paste: public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [][] startArr = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
  int [][] testArr = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(startArr, testArr));
 }